# Reactjs input keeps another input's value on toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two inputs, first `phone` second `code` and you can toggle between those. if you click on toggle button it works good, but there is problem, if you type something in first input, this value show on second input too! any idea how to fix this??

```
function Example() {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);


  return (
    <div>
      {!confirm ? <input placeholder="phone" type="number" name="phone"/> 
      :
      <input placeholder="code" type="number" name="confirm"/>}
      <button onClick={() => setConfirm(!confirm)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/mysg0fkj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `key` for each input. to make the `input`s totally replaced.

```
function Example() {
const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);


  return (
    <div>
      {!confirm ? <input key="1" placeholder="phone" type="number" name="phone"/> 
      :
      <input key="2" placeholder="code" type="number" name="confirm"/>}
      <button onClick={() => setConfirm(!confirm)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any technical explanation for why this happen? but with this on toggle it remove previous value

Comment: Without the key for each element, the `input` will not totally removed when toggle the button, but it's attributes will change and will get the value of the previous `input`, Also if you want preserve the value of each input you should use `state`

Comment: @tourtravel React reuse the `input` element. https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html